# Derive frequency given potential using Newton's laws

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, potential-energy, frequency

A mass with mass $m$ has a potential energy function $U(x)$ and I'm wondering how you would find the frequency of small oscillations about equilibrium points using Newton's laws.

I started by finding where $$\frac{d U}{d x} = 0$$

but I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

I also know from Newton's 2nd Law that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{F} &= m \mathbf{\ddot{x}} \\ 
 -\frac{\partial U }{\partial x}&= m \mathbf{\ddot{x}}
\end{align}

but I'm not sure where to continue this approach either because there is an expression in terms of displacement on the LHS, and an expression in terms of time on the RHS. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Find a similar question here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118708/lagrangian-formulation-of-the-problem-small-oscillations-around-an-equilibrium. There is a large theory of small oscillations around the equilibrium point and a fantastic walkthrough is given by Goldstein in his book of classical mechanics (a must read). If you just have one particle though, usually the frequency is given by second order derivative of the potential around the equilibrium point.

Answer (score 3):

It's always possible to expand the potential in Taylor series around any local minima (in this example $U(x) $ has local minima at $x_0$ , thus  $U'(x_0)=0 $ )

$$ U(x) \approx U(x_0)+\frac{1}{2}U''(x_0)(x-x_0)^2 $$

Setting $ U(x_0)=0 $ and $ x_0=0$ (for simplicity, the result don't depend on this) and equating to familiar simple harmonic oscillator potential we get -

$$ \frac{1}{2}kx^2=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2=\frac{1}{2}U''(x_0)x^2 $$

Thus -

$$ \omega =\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}=\sqrt{\frac{U''(x_0)}{m}} $$

Comment: You have to include the additional hypothesis that you are only looking at _small_ oscillations, otherwise also other terms in higher order displacements $o(x-x_0)^2$ will occur.

Comment: That's part of the question

Comment: I had a similar problem but the potential was not quadratic. The top answer here works only for quadratic in which you only have a minimum. This link should be helpful for higher order potentials! https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Classical_Mechanics_(Dourmashkin)/23%3A_Simple_Harmonic_Motion/23.07%3A_Small_Oscillations

Comment: @KimLong the whole point is to derive the oscillation frequency of arbitrary potential very close to its stable minima. Read again the question and the answer. The link you've provided shows exactly the same method.